# how to print elements of a 1D array into a N x N box

Tags: java, arrays

i have to use a 1D array to create a box. keep in mind i am NOT allowed using a 2D array.

so far here is my code:

```
String input = "";

    int N = InputNumber(input);
    char [] Board = new char[N];
    int M = (int) Math.sqrt(N);

    System.out.println("Printing " + (M) + " x " + (M) + " board...");

    char A = 'O';
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(Board.length); i++)
    {
        Board[i] = A;
        System.out.println(Board[i]);
    }
```

the user choses a number, after which the program creates a box.
so for example if N = 4 the program should creates a 16 element array that prints like this:

```
OOOO
OOOO
OOOO
OOOO
```

this box is then gonna be treated as x and y coordinates and additional methods will be added where the user inputs x and y coordinates and the O will switch to an X. i am just not so sure how to split up the array so that it would print as needed. my program just iterates the elements of the array and prints them out in one line...

Comment: Go Until `Board.length` and do inside `if( (i % N) == 0) ) System.out.println();` and when creating the char array wouldn't you need to do `char [] Board = new char[N*N];` since you want it to be `16` long

Comment: i have another method...    InputNumber();  which creates the desired number for the array. also i used char [] Board because i was not sure how else to print out the 'O' characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create n*n array ex:- if the user enters 4 then the array should be 4*4 = 16 elements

```
int N = InputNumber(input);
char A = 'O';
char [] board = new char[N*N];
int m = (int) Math.sqrt(N); //i don't know why you need this

System.out.println("Printing " + N + " x " + N + " board...");
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
    board[i] = A;
    if((i%N) == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }
     System.out.print(board[i]);
}
```

Comment: i stated above that i am not allowed using 2 D arrays

Comment: @RonLevitzky my bad i didn't see it , i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
int n = 4; //change this back to what you had for user input and stuff
char [] board = new char[n*n];
Arrays.fill(board, 'O');
int m = (int) Math.sqrt(n); //no idea why you need this?

System.out.println("Printing " + (n) + " x " + (n) + " board...");
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
    if((i%n) == 0)
        System.out.println();
     System.out.print(board[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Printing 4 x 4 board...

OOOO
OOOO
OOOO
OOOO
```

Comment: this is a good answer but i forgot to mention that i am in a simple comp sci class and we have not gone over the Array.fill or other methods. just looking for the simplest answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let the 1D array only contain your values, now to point a  particular value using coordinates this method works well:

```
// Using 0-index based representation.
// if user entered (1,3) i.e. 0th row and 3rd element(2nd index element)
public int getPosition(int x,int y,int N)
{
   int val1 = (x-1) * N;
   int val2 = y;
   int targetIndex = val1 + val2;   // this will point to 3rd value (index will be 2) in array

   return (targetIndex -1 );
}
```

The above method will return index of (x,y) in 1D array. So, you have just used an 1D array to act as box of N*N.

Comment: this didnt solve my problem but you offered additional help on another method. thanks a lot!